# C# X509 usb certificate hangs application

Tags: c#, smartcard, x509

I'm trying to find out why my application hangs on exit, after the use of a usb token certificate.
Without any try/catch blocks or other logic, the code is:

```
X509Store s= new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
s.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2 cert = s.Certificates[0];
s.Close();

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = cert.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
byte[] cryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"), true);

rsa = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsa.Decrypt(cryptedData, true));
```

When I run the code inside a button click event, I am prompted for the PIN of the USB token. After I type and confirm the PIN , the variable x == "test", which is to be expected. Therefore encryption and decryption with the token work.

When I close the form, the application just hangs, and, if I click "break all" in VS2017, even visual studio hangs. My guess is that something related to the usb-token cryptography functions is not released/closed.

I've tried, without any luck, with:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
cert.Reset();
rsa.Clear();
rsa.Dispose();
cert.Dispose();
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the X509 usb certificate.  I may be wrong.  I suspect it is with the closing of the form.  I bet if you comment out the code posted you will still get the hanging.  Is the project a Window Form Project?   Do you have only one class in the project? Is the form the main form?  I suspect you are getting an unhandled exception during the exit.  It sound like it is in the Net Library.  I would open in control panel the event viewer and check for exceptions at the time the app was run.

Comment: There is no other code inside the application. Commenting the above x509 code causes normal behavior on exit. There is no exception upon exit.

Comment: Did you check the event viewer?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, there are no entries

Comment: Did you check the processes in Task Manager?  I would also try a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  I suspect it is an issue with a virus checker.

Comment: I've got the same problem, sadly nothing works except upgrading to .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5.0, it works fine on those runtimes.